# How to count an element having the same class using tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, jquery, count, element, tampermonkey

I would like to implement a script in tampermonkey that can count a specific class for example (main) and give a popup of the total count after the page fully loads

I am new to javascript and dont know anything please help

Comment: So how to get the report usig var countreport

Answer (score 0):

You can find them using `querySelectorAll`

```
document.querySelectorAll(".main").length
```